# Javascript using this.function results in 'has no method' error

Tags: javascript

I have this simple Javascript object that calls its own prototype method in one of its local methods. [SEE MY EDIT]

```
var Obj = function() {
    function inner() {
        this.exported();
    }

    this.exported = function() {
        alert("yay!");
    };
};

var test = new Obj();
Obj.exported();
```

However, I get the error `TypeError: Object function() {...}  has no method 'exported'`.
Any idea how this should be done?

EDIT:
whoops, just realized I never called inner(), but thanks Patrick for answering that part anyways. Here is a better example

```
var Obj = function() {

    this.exported = function() {
        inner();
    };

    function inner() {
        this.yay();
    }

    this.yay = function() {
        alert("yay!");
    };
};

var test = new Obj();
test.exported();
```

I get `TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'exported'`

Comment: There are no any prototype functions in your code btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to call exported you need to call it off the variable you assigned the instance to:

```
test.exported();
```

Also for the `inner` function you cannot use `this` there to access the Obj object as it refers to `window`.
save a reference to `this` and then use that to call the function

```
var Obj = function() {
    var _this = this;
    function inner() {
        _this.exported();
    }

    this.exported = function() {
        alert("yay!");
    };
};
```

Comment: true - but this has nothing to do with the question. `inner()` isn't called anywhere.

Comment: but according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/1852456) the `this` refers to the top level object

Comment: ok I think I get it now, `this` refers to the object prototype, not the current instance of the object?

Comment: @woojoo666, actually it refers to the global object, but that means it is `window` not Obj. Look at point 3 in that answer, when a function is executed without a context `this` refers to `window`. And since you have to execute `inner` without a context, ie `inner();`, so `this` will be `window`.

Comment: I thought inner was executed from the context of Obj, because it is in Obj's scope?

Comment: @woojoo666 the function called inner is available on a special scope called closure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures This is sometimes used to simulate private members. As zerkms pointed out; you're not using prototype and the disadvantage of simulating instance specific private members is that the functions that need to access them can't be put on the prototype. More information about prototype here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 3):

should be used

```
test.exported();
```

instead of

```
Obj.exported();
```

You should invoked `exported()` method over the `test` object, not over the `Obj` constructor.

**UPDATE**

After reached inside the `function inner(){...}`.  `this` is refers to global `window` not `Obj`, so pass the actual object `this` from `inner(this)` and do invoke `export()` from that passed object into `function inner(cthis){...}`, something like.

```
function inner(cthis) {
    //----------^--get Obj on here
    cthis.exported();
}

this.exported2 = function() {
    inner(this);
   //------^--pass Obj from here
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nQM8Y/)